# get data from SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with these four columns:

```
ID, TCname, Status, Date
```

I am storing the testcase name and status and date in this table. I want to get below data from this table.

1. no of new test cases added today.(test case not present yesterday but present today)
2. Test case fail yesterday but pass today.
3. same Test case fail yesterday and today.

Thanks

Comment: Please add any attempts you have made to solve the question

Comment: I have tried below approach but it return all failure          select tc_name FROM [TestcaseTb] where ( (status='FAIL') AND (Date ='09/09/2014' OR  Date ='09/10/2014') )

Comment: Your data seems to be denormalized. From what I gather, if you have a test case named 'testA', you have as many records with TCname = 'testA' as many days the test case has been around, is that correct? So, if testA has been in use for 10 days, there are 10 records?
Another assumption of mine: the datatype of Date column is `DATE`, not `DATETIME`, is taht right? Please post all datatypes in your question.

Comment: How come you accepted as answer a query that is clearly wrong? It selects the count of all cases that are present in the database as of today, and the pass/fail queries are clearly wrong too - it's just simple logic to see it... Can you correctly verify the results? I'm starting to doubt...
Some of the queries work correctly on the fiddles due to trivial data - honestly, should I post counter-examples?

Comment: Hi Pawel, Yes first query have issue it selecting all the records added today. Actually answer accepted by mistake. could you help me with first query. I have added one more column block name ID, TCname, Status, Date, blockname. I need the record of today date for this particular block.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only inserting new records in the table and not updating old ones.

First example:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM [TABLE_NAME] WHERE Date >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 0)
```

Second example:

```
SELECT ID, TCName, Status, Date 
  FROM [TABLE_NAME] 
 WHERE TCname IN (SELECT TCname 
                    FROM [TABLE_NAME] 
                   WHERE Date >=  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,1,GETDATE()), 0)  
                     AND Date <= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 0) 
                     AND Status = 'Fail'
                 ) 
   AND Status = 'Pass'`
```

Third example:

```
SELECT ID, TCName, Status, Date 
  FROM [TABLE_NAME] 
 WHERE TCname IN (SELECT TCname 
                    FROM [TABLE_NAME] 
                   WHERE Date >=  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,1,GETDATE()), 0)  
                     AND Date <= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 0) 
                     AND Status = 'Fail'
                ) 
   AND Status = 'Fail'`
```

Comment: Thanks Osahon, your first and 2nd query working without any issue. But 3 query returning all fail testcases for yesterday and today. but I need only repeated fail test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the type of the `Date` column is `DATE` (not `DATETIME`) and that every day you insert a single record for every test case (that exists as of that day, obviously)

**Here is a fiddle so you can verify it works like you need to:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c627/5

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cases c WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cases sub_c 
WHERE sub_c.TCname = c.TCname
AND sub_c.Date <= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0))

SELECT TCname FROM cases c WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cases sub_c 
WHERE sub_c.TCname = c.TCname 
AND sub_c.Date = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
AND sub_c.Status = 'PASS') 
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cases sub_c 
WHERE sub_c.TCname = c.TCname
AND sub_c.Date = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0) 
AND sub_c.Status = 'FAIL')
GROUP BY c.TCname

SELECT TCname FROM cases c WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cases sub_c 
WHERE sub_c.TCname = c.TCname 
AND sub_c.Date = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
AND sub_c.Status = 'FAIL') 
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cases sub_c 
WHERE sub_c.TCname = c.TCname
AND sub_c.Date = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0) 
AND sub_c.Status = 'FAIL')
GROUP BY c.TCname
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your Date column is `DATETIME`

1.No of new test cases added today

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS [New Test Case Count]
FROM Testcase 
WHERE DATE >= DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

2.Test case that failed yesterday but passed today

```
SELECT DISTINCT TCname
FROM Testcase 
WHERE TCName IN (SELECT TCName 
                 FROM Testcase t 
                 WHERE Date BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 1, GETDATE())) 
                                AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) 
                 AND t.Status = 'FAIL')
AND DATE >= DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
AND Status = 'PASS'
```

3.Test cases failed both yesterday and today. [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e38f8/2)

```
SELECT DISTINCT TCname
FROM Testcase 
WHERE TCName IN (SELECT TCName 
                 FROM Testcase t 
                 WHERE t.Date >= DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 1, GETDATE())) 
                 AND t.Date < DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) 
                 AND t.Status = 'FAIL')
AND DATE >= DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
AND Status = 'FAIL'
```

Comment: Thanks Srikanth, your 1st and 2nd query working fine. But 3rd query  returning all distinct fail test cases for yesterday and today.

Comment: Can you add some sample input and output data to your question and explain what you want?

Comment: There is some problem in first query. actually I need the testcases that not present in yesterday, newly added but this query returning the total test cases added today.